# "Cannot find module" when deploying Node.js app to Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to deploy a simple Node.js express application to Google App Engine (flex environment).

The application runs great locally.   When I try to deploy to App Engine, I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './app/models/xyz'
```

My app directory structure looks like:

```
server.js

app/models/xyz.js
```

In `server.js`, I require the `xyz.js` file as follows:

```
const Xyz = require('./app/models/xyz');
```

If I move the `xyz.js` file to the same root folder as `server.js`, everything deploys and works great.

This is the first node.js app that I try to deploy to Google App Engine.  Do I need to configure the path to `app/models/xyz.js` in my `app.yaml`?    None of the reference applications seem to require this?

Comment: Did you ever fix this?

Answer (score 0):

For small, simple projects, all the app's files can live in one directory. You are right, you may need to configure the path to "app/models/xyz.js" in your app.yaml, or rather using more than one *.yaml file, as described in the [Organizing Configuration Files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuration-files) document.